# How to pull data from a random cell on page load in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

Basically, I'm just trying to figure out how to make a cell pull a random cell's value within a range at random when the page loads.

For example, have cell A1 pull a cell at random from range B1:B20 and refresh when the page is refreshed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(VLOOKUP(QUERY({ROW(B1:B20), 
 RANDBETWEEN(ROW(B1:B20)^0, 999^99)}, "select Col1 order by Col2"), 
 {ROW(B1:B20), B1:B20}, 2, 0), 1, 1))
```

[image: 0]